# .htaccess Rewrite QSA

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So I have an htaccess file that I'm working on for someone, and I'm stuck on passing the URL arguments. Basically any and all arguments need to be passed, however I don't know all the queries, which is where I get lost and need help.

I've literally spent the past hour and a half digging through the internet and read about QSA's but have just gotten completely lost... Needless to say, I'm not well with htaccess files. Lines 1-23 are for something else related, but with the pages themselves.

Here's a few examples in case you're confused: 
"/events/?query=dark needs to execute events.php?query=dark"
"http://mywebsite.com/authorize/?name=john would actually execute http://mywebsite.com/authorize.php?name=john"

Here's what I have so far, line 25 and down is just an official query I have atm.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "domain"/$1 [R=301,L]

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  /events/?$      [NC]
RewriteRule .*  /events.php [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  /authentication/?$      [NC]
RewriteRule .*  /authentication.php [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  /databases/?$      [NC]
RewriteRule .*  /databases.php [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} name=(.*)
RewriteRule ^authorize/(.*) /authorize.php?name=%1
```

Comment: And `RewriteRule ^(authorize|events)/ $1.php [QSA]` does not do what you want?

Comment: Remove the `R=301` everywhere